# Trying to find the "true" location of my files in localhost, create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand that web-pack bundles all my files into one location. What I am trying to find out is what the actual file path to my assets folder.

I many files that are just storage for images, .js and css files. the `url` variable. `"url": "files/assets/13537138/1/asset.css"` seems to be pointing to the wrong directory because it is not reading anything.

I had the same problem with images but I found out `"img": "/static/media/test.32adf318.jpg",`  was the correct directory by dragging the image to the url box in chrome.

`src file path`

[image]

```js
"13537138": {
      "data": null,
      "file": {
        "filename": "asset.css",
        "size": 750,
        "hash": "b114a35ae9f99d49457c3d933db32b9f",
        "url": "files/assets/13537138/1/asset.css"
      },
      "name": "css",
      "preload": true,
      "region": "eu-west-1",
      "revision": 1,
      "tags": [],
      "type": "css",
      "id": "13537138"
    },
```

Comment: I found out my image locationg by using `<img  className = "MainImage" src = {require('./imgFolder/test.jpg')}/>` , than I dragged the image to find the true file path.

Comment: local images must always be referred to using `require`. `{ url: " " }` is for network images.